# Send POST HTTP request to google calendar/v3 API return parse error

Tags: json, delphi, http, httprequest, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to send HTTP requests to the Google Calendar/v3 API using the REST client library components in DELPHI XE5 Update2(`TRESTClient`, `TRESTRequest`, `TRESToAuth2Autenticator`, `TRESTResponse`). After settings this components in Delphi IDE, GET requests is working well, returning desired JSON response.

But POST request (https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events) with a parameter in `TRESTRequest.params` setting up as `pkREQUESTBODY` with option `poDoNotEncode` and a value of:

```json
{
   "end":{
      "date":"2014-06-13"
   },
   "start":{
      "date":"2014-06-13"
   },
   "summary":"reTest"
}
```

returns a Google API error:

```json
{
   "error":{
      "errors":[
         {
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"parseError",
            "message":"This API does not support parsing form-encoded input."
         }
      ],
      "code":400,
      "message":"This API does not support parsing form-encoded input."
   }
}
```

This code and parameters is working well in DELPHI XE6 , not in XE5.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  rBody: TStringStream;
begin
  rBody := TStringStream.Create('{"end": {"date": "2014-06-13"},"start": {"date": "2014-06-13"},"summary": "reTest"}');
  RESTRequest.AddBody(rBody, ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
  RESTRequest.Execute;
end;
```

Is there someting I'm doing wrong , how can I do to get the request working ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You are not setting up the RESTRequest correctly. Most likely, you are not setting the request body's `ContentType` to `ctAPPLICATION_JSON`.  By default, a single-parameter RESTRequest will use `ctAPPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED` unless you specify otherwise.  This is stated in the documentation:

[REST.Client.TRESTRequestParameter.ContentType](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequestParameter.ContentType):

> When this parameter is left empty, the content type will be chosen basically depending on the number of existing parameters, that go into the requests body.
>    **A single-parameter request uses application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, while a multiple-parameter request uses multipart/mixed instead.

That would explain why the server is complaining about the data being form-encoded.  It is looking at the body's `Content-Type` header, sees an unsupported value, and reports an error back to you ignoring the actual body data you sent.

Comment: I have tryed that with only one TRESTRequest.params: contentType setting up as ctAPPLICATION_JSON , kind setting up as pkREQUESTBODY and value setting up as{
   "end":{
      "date":"2014-06-13"
   },
   "start":{
      "date":"2014-06-13"
   },
   "summary":"reTest"
}
and I have the same error response, HTTP/1.0 error n°400, 
This API does not support parsing form-encoded input
I dont know what to do else

Comment: Please show your actual code. I am famailiar with the REST protocol, but not very familiar with `TRESTRequest` yet. It sounds like you are still not setting the ContentType correctly. It needs to be set at the top level of the request. Maybe you are setting it at the body level, which might cause `TRESTRequest` to send `multipart/form-data` as the top level ContentType of the  request instead. Can you show the actual HTTP data being transmitted?

Comment: This code and parameters is working well in DELPHI XE6 , not in XE5. I'am very disappointed, compare to the price aff this tool !!!

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
rBody:TStringStream;
begin
rBody:=TStringStream.Create('{"end": {"date": "2014-06-13"},"start": {"date": "2014-06-13"},"summary": "reTest"}');
RESTRequest.AddBody(rBody,ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
RESTRequest.Execute;
end;

Comment: That code should have been added to your original question, not posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the API description at

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

it looks like the JSON part belongs in the POST request body.

The error message sounds like the JSON part is encoded as a HTML form field value (you can verify this with a HTTP proxy like Fiddler2).

Hint: If you have a working client based in a different language, you can use Fiddler2 to compare the working and the non-working requests to find out what is wrong.